# 2 or more foreign key levels for Django Queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

Let's say I have a database relation model as so:

A `loan` is associated to 1 `customer`. It contains multiple books. Each `book` has an 1 `author`. In Django queryset, I want to obtain the author's description for all loans.

So using `get_related`, I only hit the DB once instead of multiple times if I do this:

```
loans = Loan.objects.filter(id=current_loan).get_related('consists_of_book')
```

How can I extend this to the `author` foreign key? This answer does not look like the correct answer to me:

```
loans = Loan.objects.filter(id=current_loan).get_related('consists_of_book').get_related('written_by_author')
```

Comment: Please show real code. There is no `get_related` method on Django querysets.

Comment: There is no `get_related` method in the queryset. There is `select_related`. Levels are separated by '__' (2 underscore). I think you need something like this `loans = Loan.objects.filter(id=current_loan).select_related('consists_of_book', 'consists_of_book__writen_by_author')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use the double underscore notation like so:

```
loans = Loan.objects.filter(id=current_loan)
    .prefetch_related('consists_of_book', 'consists_of_book__written_by_author')
```

Comment: I would say `select_related` will also do the trick given my DB models but yours will handle the general case. Exactly!